# How can I use provided keys to get root shell access?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, login, credentials

I have been given values, for an AWS instance, for the keys of AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretKey provided in the hope that I may be able to do some stuff with Apache.

Is there any way, on this information, that I could connect with the server with root console access?

If there is other information needed, such the server's IP, that I could ask for? If I have to ask for him to request information, what can he request for me?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely can not get ssh access to the instance with the AccessKeyId and SecretKey. Those are used to authenticate API calls to the AWS API.

There is the [System Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/) service. Part of this service is the `Session Manager`. The session manager allows to get ssh access from a web console which could be accessed with the credentials you were given. That service requires a agent on the instance to be running

However most likely you were given the wrong credentials. ssh authentication on AWS is the same as any normal VM. Usually you just add the public key to a user with sudo privileges.

AWS deploys a ssh key when you launch a new VM, other than that there is nothing special about ssh authentication with instances running in AWS.